# Error deploying Django app on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, django-rest-framework

I'm kinda new to Django as well as heroku and have encountered a problem while publishing my app to heroku. The error I get is this:

```
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to shielded-lake-72150.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/shielded-lake-72150.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/shielded-lake-72150.git'
```

I tried a lot of solutions given online, but nothing worked. I even set the buildpack to python and added requirements.txt file. But it still shows me the same error. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You surelly miss a `requirements.txt` file, check the error message, it gives you a link: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure

Comment: @Arount I have pipfile instead of requirements.txt. Shouldn't it work??

Comment: Tbh, I don't know, but anyway having a `requirements.txt` is **the** good practice. I'm pretty sure Heroku expect that (just do `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, add it, commit it, push it and check if it worked)

Comment: @Arount Tried, still didn't work :(

Comment: Hmm, are we ok you can execute your code locally without errors?

Comment: @Arount ya, tested few times now. Working fine

Comment: After you added the `requirements.txt` to you repository and pushed to Heroku, I believe the error message should have changed. If so, please paste the error message so we can check if there's any useful information.

Comment: @Arount It's telling me to add Procfile. How to do that??

Comment: Hoo that's true, I had forgotten that Heroku was using Procfile (even if it's the root of Heroku..) https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Comment: @Arount Deployed successfully . But now when I open the webpage it shows 'Application error'. I made an API, how to access it?? And the admin panel?